# Decrease value in a number column using a query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm looking to create an SQL query which will decrease a value in a column by 1 every time it is ran.

Simple Table with 3 columns -

```
Name - Number - Created
Dan      20    20/03/2019
```

I want to decrease the Number by one every time I run the query.

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET number = number - 1 WHERE Name = ?` ?

Comment: use trigger!!!!!

Comment: Thank you GMB - Can't believe it was that simple!

Answer (score 1):

`update [table] set Number = (Number - 1)`

Comment: Close, but not close enough. The way you wrote it, it would update **all rows** in the table.

Comment: I know and I wrote the sentence that way on purpose. I assume that it knows how to specify where the conditions on what to apply it to.